# Sort Properties of my Control in Expression Blend designer

Tags: c#, .net, expression-blend, blend, expression-blend-4

I created my new Category "MyCategory" to store all my Properties of my Control, in design mode (Expression Blend 4), like theses categories:

[image]

By default, all my properties under my Category are sorted alphabetically.

Is it possible to choose the order ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is. As categories attribute doesn't have a field to specify position and it could be only specified in the attribute parameters.